# Fileupload application not working as jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring boot application. User selects server of their choice and a file on their local system and the file gets SFTP to that server.

This works by: input stream reading the file into a folder within the root project. The sftp method needs the file path to work. Since I'm unable to get the file path of the file on the users system and just get the file, I bring it locally and then supply the path from there.

This work perfectly when running my project from intellij and NOT so perfectly when packaged as a jar.

After some reading, it looks like it's not great to bring in a file into a jar. Any ideas on a route to take now? Thanks

```
public void SFTP(MultipartFile file, String friendlyName, String filePath) throws Exception {
    String host = "10.3.152.245"; //host:IP
    String user = "cloud";
    String password = "Password1";
    System.out.println("File path: " + filePath);
    try {
        String fileName = renameLocal(file);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);

        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();

        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();

        sftpChannel.cd("/");
        sftpChannel.cd(filePath);

        sftpChannel.put("\\upload-dir\\" + fileName, ".");
        sftpChannel.rename(filePath + "/" + fileName, filePath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());

        session.disconnect();
        sftpChannel.disconnect();

        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".\\upload-dir\\" + fileName);
        Files.delete(path);
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

the method above is the SFTP method that's called when a user uploads a file. Static host user and pass for now. As you see, I'm putting the file locally (method not here) in the upload-dir. Then providing upload-dir\filename to the sftpChannel.put method

Comment: You could read your file into an inputstream and the put this inputstream in the put method. Have you tried that?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli worked out great.. thank you!